# Compare data between key of MongoDB using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collections like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6266caf163a028f3c4c574e2'), 'company': 'aaaa', 'name': 'John', 'phone': '55 123 456'}
{'_id': ObjectId('6266caf163a028f3c4aj1s21'), 'company': 'bbbb', 'name': 'Olive', 'phone': '55 987 654'}
{'_id': ObjectId('6266caf163a028f3c4aj1121'), 'company': 'bbbb', 'name': 'Jonathon', 'phone': '66 981 761'}
```

And I have a list like this;

```
companyListpython = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

I need a comparison/data in a for loop like this using pymongo;

```
for company1 in all_collections:
    for company2 in companyListpython:
        if company1 == company2:
            print(company1, name, phone)
            print("do smt")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't do a simple `$in` on query level like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9j8zNek226P)?

Comment: It was easy, really thanks.